# Should `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` accept only INFO level of logging?

Tags: python, logging

Here is the sample code from source: `https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html`

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
logging.error('And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö')
```

I thought the `level=logging.DEBUG` of below code

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

making the `logging` accept only `logging.DEBUG` only. Then why `info`, `warning`, `error` work

Comment: No, your logger accepts all levels from `logging.DEBUG` and above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The logging levels of python is arranged in the following order:

1. CRITICAL
2. ERROR
3. WARNING
4. INFO
5. DEBUG
6. NOTSET

If you set the root logger level when configuring as `logging.DEBUG`, it will write all the logs with the levels above that.

Example:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', encoding='utf-8', level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
logging.error('And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö')
```

Output:

```
DEBUG:root:This message should go to the log file
INFO:root:So should this
WARNING:root:And this, too
ERROR:root:And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö
```

If you set the root logger level when configuring as `logging.ERROR`, it will write only the CRITICAL logs and ERROR logs.

Example:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.ERROR)
logging.warning('this is warning')
logging.info('this is info')
logging.error('And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö')
logging.critical('And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö 2')
```

Output:

```
ERROR:root:And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö
CRITICAL:root:And non-ASCII stuff, too, like Øresund and Malmö 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Log levels are actually integers and they set a threshold. For instance `logging.DEBUG` is 10 and `logging.INFO` is 20. When you set a log level, you allow that level *and anything larger*. When you set `DEBUG` any level 10 or greater will log. [Filter objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) are commonly used if you want a different level of control.